# Commerce Node Checkout free option skip cart/checkout/payment

Tags: 7, commerce

I am working on a free/paid listing site. I setup Commerce Node Checkout with Node Checkout Expire and have a free version(14 days) and a paid "featured" option (30 days). The paid option should go to cart->checkout->payment while the free option should act and behave as if Drupal Commerce wasn't installed.

I was looking around rules but I can't seem to find the proper events/conditions/actions to basically treat free listings as regular drupal nodes. I don't really want to track orders for free listings, but I also don't want to mess Drupal Commerce's reporting up either.

Can rules do this? And if so, what would be the proper events/conditions/actions to bypass Commerce all together and just publish the node if "free listing" is selected under listing options for Node Checkout.

Thanks

Comment: Hi,have you found a solution to this?I am interested in bypassing checkout based on a role.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom module that implements hook_node_submit() and that sets

```
$form_state['values']['commerce_node_checkout_skip'] = True;
```

if the free version is selected.

Comment: You could also use rules to do this if you preferred.

Comment: @rooby:Could you please tell me how can I do this with rules?thank you

Comment: Also I tried this code but it didn't work:
 function custom_node_submit() {
 global $user;
 if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
  $form_state['values']['commerce_node_checkout_skip'] = True;
}

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
function custom_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state) {
```

global $user;

if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
  $form_state['values']['commerce_node_checkout_skip'] = True;
  $node->status = 1;
    }

return $form;

}